# Reliable wireless Battery charging

Tags: iphone, charging

Charging my Iphone 6s with a cable has become a real headache for me, where the cables keep getting "broken" and not charging

Is there an alternative way to charge in a cable-free way?

Comment: [Maxfield](http://maxfield.de/shop/?lang=en) makes the best iphone wireless charging cases I've ever used. They fit really tight and don't add a lot of bulk. You will need a Qi charging pad to go with the case. Few things to consider: **1.** Most wireless charging cases for iphone won't have a secondary charging port, in which case, you will have to remove the case to charge with a cable. **2.** Drop the phone enough times and these will break too. **3.** Charging is fairly slow and heats up the phone quite a lot. I would not recommend overnight charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology you may looking for is 'QI wireless charging'.

There are covers like [LingsFire® 2 in 1 Qi Wireless Cover](https://www.amazon.de/LingsFire%C2%AE-Wireless-Ladeger%C3%A4t-Schutzh%C3%BClle-Aktiviert-Iphone-6-schwarz/dp/B00WJN29PA) (German link) using that technology and there are other approaches like [LEAPCOVER Universal-QI Wireless Receiver Patch](https://www.amazon.de/LEAPCOVER-Universal-QI-Wireless-Receiver-Patch-Lade/dp/B01IM6A4GS/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1486724702&sr=8-3&keywords=qi%20iphone) (German link as well) where you can actually fit it into your iPhone.

I found a link for you addressing that: www.forbes.com/sites/ewanspence/2014/12/11/qi-wireless-charger-iphone-6/#2d1685987fb2

You may also do a Google search with the keywords 'qi' and 'iphone'.